# Android - ViewPager resumption on back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, back-button

I have a ViewPager that has 4-6 categories of products.  When a user clicks on a product they get taken to a new Fragment. When they hit back, they get sent back to the ViewPager and everything has to reload and all pagination has been lost. I can save on the reloading by caching the results, but ideally if the user is 26 results in, they should be returned to their exact scroll position. However, 26 results in could be 2 pages worth of pagination as well (we use endless scrolling).
I'm surprised Android doesn't have  a built in mechanism to handle this routine scenario. Am I missing something?

Code:

This is how I'm adding a Fragment:

```
private void addFragment(AppFragment fragment)
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, fragment).addToBackStack(fragment.getTitle()).commit();

    }
```

I have nothing in onResume, the only 2 methods I use are OnCreateView and OnActivityCreated

Comment: Can you show some (relevant part of) of the code? Because `ViewPager` does save and restore the last known position when it is saved. Are you perchance resetting the adapter in `onResume()`?

Comment: @dhke No I just confirmed this. I have a network call in onActivityCreated but other than that, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Dirty and simpliest solutuon is create a new activity within fragment inside. Show your data to there. Whenever the user presses back button, he will see previous activity.

But, if system deletes your data from ram (if user spends much time in other activities or navigates more), you need to restore states. Basicly, restore your data and create new pager adapter. Then you need to set it to view pager and call setCurrentPage(position).

Good luck there :)

Answer (score 0):

You should set offscreen limit property in ViewPager.
 
`ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

Comment: Sorry this is not dealing with the issue described.